# Is it possible to use WPF ResourceDictionary with parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, parameters, resourcedictionary

I have stored some icons as XAML-Code in the resourcedictionary, e.g.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Question">
    <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M10,14L6,14 6,9C6,8.232,6.29,7.531,6.765,7L4,7 4,5C4,3.262 5.682,2 8,2 10.316,2 12,3.262 12,5L12,7C12,8.304,11.164,9.416,10,9.828z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF414141" Geometry="F1M9,11L7,11 7,13 9,13z M9,10L7,10 7,9C7,7.897,7.897,7,9,7L9,5.203C8.84,5.115 8.495,5 8,5 7.504,5 7.159,5.115 7,5.203L7,6 5,6 5,5C5,3.841 6.261,3 8,3 9.738,3 11,3.841 11,5L11,7C11,8.103,10.102,9,9,9z" />
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem: width and height are fixed values. So i changed the fixed values to "Auto" without any error in the resourcedictionary.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionAuto">
    <Viewbox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <Rectangle Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M10,14L6,14 6,9C6,8.232,6.29,7.531,6.765,7L4,7 4,5C4,3.262 5.682,2 8,2 10.316,2 12,3.262 12,5L12,7C12,8.304,11.164,9.416,10,9.828z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF414141" Geometry="F1M9,11L7,11 7,13 9,13z M9,10L7,10 7,9C7,7.897,7.897,7,9,7L9,5.203C8.84,5.115 8.495,5 8,5 7.504,5 7.159,5.115 7,5.203L7,6 5,6 5,5C5,3.841 6.261,3 8,3 9.738,3 11,3.841 11,5L11,7C11,8.103,10.102,9,9,9z" />
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then i used the icon in my view with setting the width and height values, but nothing is shown. the "fixed" icon works, the "auto" icon not.

```
    <ContentPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Question32}"
                      Margin="20,0">
    </ContentPresenter>
```

vs.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionAuto}"
                  Margin="20,0"
                  Width="64"
                  Height="64">
</ContentPresenter>
```

Is it possible to set width and height parameter in the xaml-view and use them in the resourcedictionary? because the xaml-icon is basically "dynamic" and a variable size would be better than guessing the width and height to fit perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better define the icons as DrawingImage resources like

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="Question">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M10,14L6,14 6,9C6,8.232,6.29,7.531,6.765,7L4,7 4,5C4,3.262 5.682,2 8,2 10.316,2 12,3.262 12,5L12,7C12,8.304,11.164,9.416,10,9.828z" />
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF414141" Geometry="F1M9,11L7,11 7,13 9,13z M9,10L7,10 7,9C7,7.897,7.897,7,9,7L9,5.203C8.84,5.115 8.495,5 8,5 7.504,5 7.159,5.115 7,5.203L7,6 5,6 5,5C5,3.841 6.261,3 8,3 9.738,3 11,3.841 11,5L11,7C11,8.103,10.102,9,9,9z" />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

and show them in an Image element like

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Question}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
```

The drawing would stretch to the desired size according to the `Stretch` property of the Image, which defaults to `Uniform`.

Comment: This would also allow to mix vector and bitmap icons, since Question could as well be a BitmapImage resource.